# New-PSDrive does not work inside of workflow/inlinescript block

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Using Powershell 3.0:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16481
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Network drives are not properly mapped using New-PSDrive when invoked from inside VM_Backup.ps1:

MonitorFramework.ps1:

```
workflow Monitoring_Local {

  parallel{

   InlineScript{$run = VM_Backup.ps1}

  }
}
```

VM_Backup.ps1:

```
$cred = REDACTED
Connect-VIServer -server "x.x.x.x" -Credential $cred

$sourcedatastore = Get-Datastore “datastore1”
$destinationdatastore = Get-Datastore “nas02”

New-PSDrive -Location (Get-Datastore “datastore1”) -Name source_datastore -PSProvider VimDatastore -Root “”
New-PSDrive -Location ( Get-Datastore “nas02”) -Name destination_datastore -PSProvider VimDatastore -Root “”
Get-PSDrive
```

The output of Get-PSDrive will show that the drives above have NOT been mapped.

When I run the VM_Backup.ps1 script directly (not invoking through MonitorFramework.PS1) the drives ARE properly mapped.

Any help/insight/suggestions would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: anybody? still stuck on this unfortunately.